# JSTL Number parsing error

Tags: jsp, jstl, parseexception

I need the current year as an integer value (e.g. 2015) stored in a variable in a JSP page.
This is the JSTL tags i'm using:

```
<jsp:useBean id="date" class="java.util.Date" />
<fmt:formatDate var="currentYear" value="${date}" pattern="yyyy" />
<fmt:parseNumber var="currentYear" integerOnly="true" type="number" value="${currentYear}" parseLocale="en-US"/>
```

And this is the error I'm facing in the Tomcat Log:

```
[javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: In <parseNumber>, value attribute can not be parsed: "Wed Apr 29 00:42:30 CEST 2015"] with root cause
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "Wed Apr 29 00:42:30 CEST 2015"
    at java.text.NumberFormat.parse(NumberFormat.java:350)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.fmt.ParseNumberSupport.doEndTag(ParseNumberSupport.java:164)
    at org.apache.jsp.new_.reports_jsp._jspx_meth_fmt_005fparseNumber_005f0(reports_jsp.java:242)
    at org.apache.jsp.new_.reports_jsp._jspService(reports_jsp.java:136)
```

Am I doing something wrong?
The strangest thing is that I see this error only in the log: if I load the page, everything works as it should and I see the correct current year.

Comment: Silly question, but you don't happen to have one or more fmt:parseNumber statements commented out with HTML comments from troubleshooting this, do ya?

Comment: that's the only parseNumber in the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used an alternative workaround for my problem:

```
<jsp:useBean id="date" class="java.util.Date" />
<c:set var="currentYear" value="${date.getYear() + 1900}" />
```